# Perl RegEx Needed for System Log

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to group everything in bold into a parser. How do I take multiple sentences and ensure they are grouped together?

> 5/1/2013 9:43:00  INFO    Principal authentication
>
> **User “admin” attempted to authenticate using authenticator
>   Token_Auth”. 
>       The user belongs to security domain “SystemDomain.Default”**
>   Success AUTHN_METHOD_SUCCESS    Authentication method success
>     company.admin   company Admin   wsnc1_2.def.comp.net
>   SystemDomain.default

Comment: What's the pattern you're looking for? It's hard to tell with just one line of sample input.

Comment: User “admin” attempted to authenticate using authenticator Token_Auth”. 
The user belongs to security domain “SystemDomain.Default”

Comment: From your example: `Principal authentication/s+(.+?)\s+Success AUTHN_METHOD_SUCCESS`

Comment: To answer we really need more example data. And ideally an attempt to solve it yourself, with an indication of where you're having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your ONE EXAMPLE (guaranteed to fail for all other examples), I would do the following:

1. tokenize your log entry
2. delete the first three tokens
3. delete everything after the last token you want

Illustrative script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>)
{
    my @line = split;
    splice(@line, 0,3);
    my $line = join(' ', @line);
    $line =~ s/Success.*//;
    print $line;
}
exit(0);

__DATA__
5/1/2013 9:43:00 INFO Principal authentication User "admin" attempted to authenticate using authenticator Token_Auth". The user belongs to security domain "SystemDomain.Default" Success AUTHN_METHOD_SUCCESS Authentication method success company.admin company Admin wsnc1_2.def.comp.net SystemDomain.default
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to splice the first 5 elements? Also, you're assuming that everything is on a single line, but I'm not sure that's true. (Hard to say due to lack of information provided by the OP.)